# postgresql - How to compare date without time?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2, the problem is how to compare date without time?

```
cur.execute("UPDATE daily_price SET price = '"+price+"' WHERE date_time = '"+date+"';")
```

date_time value in database is `2000-01-01 00:00:00+08`

variable date value is `2011-11-01 00:00:00`

what I'm looking is compare `2000-01-01 = 2000-01-01` without time

Comment: I assume when you say without time you mean both the `time` and `datetime` packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `date` is a string (looks like it, since you're concatenating it within your query), you should be able to do:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE daily_price SET price = '"+price+"' WHERE date_time::DATE = '"+date.split()[0]+"';")
```